# Blender 2.60: GLSL Shading problems on Blender Game Engine - objects not visible

Tags: mesh, texturing, game-engine, shaders

I have a problem with my blender scene when I play it on the blender game engine. When I set `GLSL shading` and play my scene using the embedded game engine (P on scene) I have no problem and all objects are correctly rendered, but when I export my scene using the `Export -> Save as game engine runtime` function, only a few objects are visible and rendered and all others are black. 
I have already tried to apply visible object materials to other objects but I have the same result: invisible/black objects.
When I change shading mode to `Multitexture` all the scene is visible, but for my purpouse I need GLSL shading.
How can I resolve this problem? Is there any problems rendering objects with multiple materials?
Note: I'm using Blender 2.60 with python 3.2 version.
Thanks

Comment: Do you need to use Blender 2.6? Maybe this bug is fixed in a newer version. The current version of Blender is 2.72b. You can get it [here](http://www.blender.org/download/).

Comment: @maddin45 Unfortunately I have to use Blender 2.60 :(